# Can't connect to froxlor clients via SFTP

Tags: 12.04, server, ssh, sftp, proftpd

I can login to root and other ssh users using **SFTP** (ProFTPD) without a problem but I can't connect via sftp to any of the **froxlor clients** that I add via the panel though.

With some help from [here](https://forum.froxlor.org/index.php/topic/12753-configuring-proftpd-to-act-as-sftp-server/), I did the following:

1. Add the following to `/etc/proftpd/modules.conf`

   `LoadModule mod_sftp.c`
2. Add the following to `/etc/proftpd/sql.conf`

   `Include /etc/proftpd/sftp.conf`
3. Create file `/etc/proftpd/sftp.conf` with following content:

   `<IfModule mod_sftp.c>
       SFTPEngine on
       SFTPLog /var/log/proftpd/sftp.log
       SFTPHostKey /etc/ssh/sshhostdsakey
       SFTPHostKey /etc/ssh/sshhostrsakey
   </IfModule>`
4. Restarted proftpd and ssh

If I try connecting via filezilla to a froxlor client with **host** sftp://server-ip **username** say, `user1` and the user password, I get the following error:

```
Error:  Authentication failed.
Error:  Critical error: Could not connect to server
```

> **Please let me know if there's any info, logs, config, etc you would want me to provide.**

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error.

**Solution:**

Do NOT put the `Include /etc/proftpd/sftp.conf` in the `IfModule mod_sql.c` section.

Place the include command in a new line after the `IfModule mod_sql.c` tag.

Comment: I have switched from Froxlor to Webmin unfortunately. But if this answer gets 4 upvotes or more from the community, I will mark it as the right answer :) Cheers